# Setting up a NAT in VM

Tags: freebsd, nat

I have two separate freeBSD VMs. In VM1 I added 2 interface.

> em0: 192.168.1.0/24
>
> em1: 192.168.2.0/24.

In VM2 I have one interface with

> 192.168.2.0/24

IP address.

In VM1 I started a NAT and now I want to see if it is work properly or not. I'm able to connect to internet with my VM2 ( internet is come through em0 on my VM1) so I know my router which is in VM1 work correctly. Is there any command to show my list of NAT translations or any other way to show that my IP has been translated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tcpdump -i em0` on VM1 and observe that all packets to and from VM1 have an address of VM1's em0 interface.

If you observe the same packets on em1, you will see this address translated.